# Upload video to Youtube from PHP script in CLI

Tags: php, youtube, command-line-interface

I want to develop for myself a way to upload my video from a PHP command.
The PHP script is located on my laptop and for this reason i don't have an external HTTP address.
I start with the PHP code provide by Youtube (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#upload_a_video), but as i use CLI i can't have the token. 
I try to found some ways but i just found old ways (old API).

Is this possible to do ? Any suggestions ?

Thanks